# Netlogo: how to see coordinates of patchset

Tags: netlogo

I have turtles with a *memory* that stores the patches the turtles travel:

```
set memory (patch-set memory patch-here)
```

How can I see the coordinates of each of the patches of its *memory*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `memory` is a patch-set, so you can `ask` its members just as you would `ask patches`. For example:

```
to inspect-memory
  ask one-of turtles [
    print word "This is the memory of " self
    ask memory [
      print list pxcor pycor
    ]
  ]
end
```

Alternatively, consider that the reporter above (i.e. `list pxcor pycor`) is just a reporter that you can apply to any patch or group of patches by using `of`. In that case:

```
to inspect-memory
  ask one-of turtles [
    print word "This is the memory of " self
    print [list pxcor pycor] of memory
  ]
end
```

The first example will report separate lists, and to me it seems mostly useful for printing. The second example will report a list of lists, so it seems more useful for further manipulation.

Anyway I don't know if you already considered this but note that, being `memory` a patch-set, **its patches will always come in random order**. If you want `memory` to mirror the journey of your turtles, then you have to make it a list:

```
turtles-own [
  memory
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1 [
    set memory (list)
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    right random 360
    move-to patch-ahead 1
    set memory (lput patch-here memory)
  ]
end
```

Considering that we now have a list of patches, you can still achieve the same type of output. The code below uses `foreach` to give you the same result as the first example above (i.e. the one returning separate lists):

```
to inspect-memory
  ask one-of turtles [
    print word "This is the memory of " self
    foreach memory [
      p ->
      ask p [
        print list pxcor pycor
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

While the code below uses `map` to give you the same result as the second example above (i.e. the one returning a list of lists):

```
to inspect-memory
    ask one-of turtles [
    print word "This is the memory of " self
    print map [p -> [list pxcor pycor] of p] memory
  ]
end
```

---

Of course, instead of printing your results to the Command Center, you can also just turn these command-procedures into reporter-procedures by using `to-report` and `report`; so that the results are readily available in other places of your code for further use if needed

---

Anyway, if this is the only way in which you are using `memory`, it leads to consider whether you can just use `memory` directly as a list of coordinates rather than an agentset/list of patches from which you have to extract that information:

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    right random 360
    move-to patch-ahead 1
    set memory (lput ([list pxcor pycor] of patch-here) memory)
  ]
end
```